# How can I simulate with a input u with ODE45 - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulation, differential-equations, ode45

I have two function handles:

```
A = @(x, y, z) [10*y - 10*x; 28*x - z*x - y; x*y - 8/3*z]
B = @(u) [u; 0; 0]
```

How can I simulate them that in MATLAB with a control variable u? Control variable u is time varying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
[t,out] = ode45(@(t,vars) myfunction(t,vars,U),tsim,xyz0);
x = out(1);
y = out(2);
z = out(3);
```

Where *U* is the value of *u*, *tsim* is the simulation time (final time o time vector) and *xyz0* is the vector of initial condition of variables *x*, *y* and *z* in the form [x0 y0 z0]. *myfunction* is defined as:

```
function dxyz= myfunction(t,vars,u)

    x = vars(1);
    y = vars(2);
    z = vars(3);

    % u varying with a condition
    if t>1
        u = newValue;
    end

    % u is a function of time u=f(t)
    u = 2*t;

    A = [10*y - 10*x; 28*x - z*x - y; x*y - 8/3*z];
    B = [u; 0; 0];
    dxyz = A+B;

end
```

Comment: But u is varying :)

Comment: Sorry! Forgott to tell you that!

Comment: How does "u" vary ? Does "u" vary with time?

Comment: Yes! Vary with time.

Comment: I have heard that interp1 can be used to interpolate a variable U from u with the length of time t.

Comment: Can you explain me what is the variation condition is and how much it varies?

Comment: I don't know the conditions and how much it varies.

Comment: Do you think `U = interp1(tsim, u, t); ` will solve the problem?

Comment: no, it didn't. _interp1_  returns interpolated values of a 1-D function at specific query points using linear interpolation (https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html?lang=en). You have to use a function that depends on time (_t_) to generate _u_ inside the function _myfunction_, I have edited my answer with two very simple examples.